# Strange behaviour html5 video on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, video

I have this problem with my website html5 video on mobile devices.
On desktop version it's all good, it works fine. The problem is on mobile. If i open sidebar push menu and then close it, my video controls disappears. I had this problem only on iphone 5s, then i changed some header and menu position settings, and now it happens on my samsung android too...No idea what to do..

I'm using video.js plugin.

Preserve-3d doesn't work:

```
video {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

I noticed, when i close the menu, the menu button remains active, could this be a lead?

http://goo.gl/jDc4LK

Comment: do you even use transform on the video?

Comment: you mean preserve-3d ? yes..
tried from external css, and as a style attribute

Comment: but what for? do you even want to transform it?

Comment: this was recommended on stackoverflow for videos on mobile especially on iphones, when something overlays html video.

Comment: Could you please give more details on "works fine".
Currently, when I am trying to open url via IOS Emulator, video is paused and menu button works fine. As soon as I put video to play, it expands to fullscreen and there is no way to hit menu button unless you leave fullscreen mode

Comment: Yes, in emulator you can't see this problem.. Practically, when the page is loaded (iphone), i see the video with native play button. If i play the video it goes in fullscreen like it should. But, if i open the menu and then close it, the native play button disappears and i see only a black area.

Comment: I watched the source code on iphone (with safari developer tools), and the video is steel there, without any changes in display or visibility..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jPushMenu.js, lines 62 - 64

```
    $('video').each(function() {
      $(this).removeAttr("controls");
    });
```

This chunk of code gets executed, when you hit "Menu button".
It removes following attribute from video tag:

```
controls="true"
```

And it causes "playback controls" getting disappeared

**EDITED**
I've checked the original script, and looks like this functionality is [not there](https://github.com/takien/jPushMenu/blob/master/js/jPushMenu.js)

I guess, you have to add similar "addAttr" lines, somewhere in the line #70 of this script, something like this:

jPushMenu.js, lines 72 - 76

```
$('.lines, .text').show();
$(".x").hide();
$('video').each(function() { 
  $(this).attr("controls","true");
});
```

btw, following should also work:

```
$('video').attr("controls","true");
```

Comment: Oh, thank you very much.. It works fine on android now, but play button steel disappear on iphone 5s.. On iphone 6 it works fine..

Comment: i just removed it for now.. Do you have any idea with this iphone problem?